# facebook like chat application in ASP.net

Tags: c#, xmpp, comet

I want to build web based facebook like lightweight chat for my site.

Website build on ASP .net on SQL server 2005.

I am interesetd in XMPP commmunication, but not able to find open source XMPP server with supportedlibrary for C# so that I can create client for my site.

Have checked googling butno luck for C# library; all I could found is plugin and jar.

Is it possible to implement chat logic and XMPP server communication in different language, and accessing thisdata through iframe or by other means on my site.

Thanks,
Hitesh.

Answer (score 3):

http://www.ag-software.de/agsxmpp-sdk/

That library seems to be pretty good.

Answer (score 2):

There are many options to send a message since first human! But how about the intelligence on it, automated collaboration in object level or shared objects among the users etc. I suggest you to take a look for the samples in **[here](http://pokein.codeplex.com)** and feel the difference.

Answer (score 2):

What you'll want to do is follow jgauffin's suggestion, and use an [XMPP library](http://www.ag-software.de/agsxmpp-sdk/) on the backend, and then typically you'd add in a comet server for integration with your web frontend (we've actually done exactly this @ Frozen Mountain, using [WebSync](http://www.frozenmountain.com/websync/)).

If you're building a smaller site and/or don't need the "realtime" aspect, you could probably get away with polling as well, in which case you'd need to store the results from the XMPP library in your own system, and poll that (since XMPP is strictly event driven).